# Tomcat configuration for development, how to add a webapp, as well as reference static files

Tags: java, tomcat, jakarta-ee, static

I want to have a web app and then configure it to load static files from a direct path.

This is the webapp configuration:

```
<Context docBase="E:\webapp1" path="/" reloadable="true"/>
```

How do I setup the static resources.

Answer (score 3):

I assume your Tomcat already can run at http://localhost:8080/

All you need to do then is to put your static resources in sub-folders of

```
E:\webapp1
```

like

```
E:\webapp1\jpg\1.jpg
E:\webapp1\css\style.css
E:\webapp1\html\abc.html
```

Change the path in Context to `""` so this webapp can run as the default webapp *i.e. the webapp name will not be part of the URL*

and you can directly serve these as

```
http://localhost:8080/jpg/1.jpg
http://localhost:8080/css/style.css
http://localhost:8080/html/abc.html
```

Is this what you were looking for? This is my understanding of your question

Comment: I gave you an up-vote because I didn't know if you set the context to blank it becomes the default context. What happens if there are two blank context's?

Comment: @Koekiebox: Tomcat refuses to start up. **WARNING: Catalina.start using conf/server.xml: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: addChild:  Child name '' is not unique**